# jquery - get text for element without children text

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example we have this file

```
<div id="mydiv">
    some text here 
    <div id="inner div">
         text for inner div
    </div>
</div>
```

i need to get `#mydiv` text only with some code like this :

```
alert($('#mydiv').text());  // will alert "some text here"
```

Comment: So you want *all* child text nodes, without more deeply nested text nodes?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

hey try this please": http://jsfiddle.net/MtVxx/2/

Good link for your specific case in here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/ (This will only get the text of the element)

Hope this helps, `:)`

**code**

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};

alert($('#mydiv').justtext());​
```

Comment: +1 for using .end(). Never knew that existed and now it's hella-usefull.

Comment: @Grinn saweet bruv, yea there are some jq apis, which are awesome to use but not widely used, :) funny that huh, thanks for plus 1.

Comment: this seems to crash in Win XP IE 8, something around `clone` or `children` still trying to figure this out..

Answer (score 26):

The currently [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362182/1338292) is pretty horrible in terms of performance, so I felt obligated to write a more lightweight one:

```
$.fn.mytext = function() {
    var str = '';

    this.contents().each(function() {
        if (this.nodeType == 3) {
            str += this.textContent || this.innerText || '';
        }
    });

    return str;
};

console.log($('#mydiv').mytext());​
```

Comment: Much better! I was looking for a way to iterate over each child of selected element, and I didn't know about `contents()`, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Like [Ja͢ck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20851691/2885620) but no need for iterating explicitly (via .each()) and collecting `textContent`s:

```
$('#mydiv').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3}).text()
```

OR, if you can use **arrow functions:**

```
$('#mydiv').contents().filter((i, el) => el.nodeType === 3).text()
```