# get text in div

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery - get text for element without children text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

I've a div with text inside and span after text like this:

```
<div>
text
<span>other text</span>
</div>
```

and I'd like to get only text in div not in span

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to be short about this: I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**.clone()**](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for that, like so:

```
b = $('div').clone();
b.children('span').remove();
alert( b.text() ); // alerts "text"
```

Using `.clone()` we can make a copy of the div, remove the span, and then get the text, all without affecting the original DOM elements displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  var myText = $('#dd').clone()            
             .children()    //select all the children
             .remove()  //remove all the children
             .end() //again go back to selected element
             .text();   //get the text of element
```

Comment: Upvoted, I like your .end() shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

```
var theText = "";
$('div').contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType === 3) theText += $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: The method is [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents). Otherwise, this works!