# How to get value of text after image tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

Here the html code

```
<span class="setcategory2">
   <img src="/images/dotes/travel.png">
TRAVEL
</span>
```

How can i get value of TRAVEL which is after img tag

Comment: if you have that mark up using `.text()` will get the text check https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/40zds36n/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get text in div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706330/get-text-in-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var imgText = $('span.setcategory2').text(); //to get the text after img

  $('div').text("The image text is: "+ imgText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="setcategory2">
   <img src="/images/dotes/travel.png">
TRAVEL
</span>

<div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to a variable like this...

```
var name = $('span').text();
```

Or if it was a specific span with an ID then...

```
var name = $("#idofspan").text();
```