# Get Inner Text from DIV

Tags: jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div id="country">
    <span>B</span>
    Bangladesh
</div>

<div id="capital">
    Dhaka
    <span>D</span>
</div>
```

1. From `#country`, I want to get **Bangladesh**
2. From `#capital`, I want to get **Dhaka**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thisis for replacing the text - but the process of getting it is included in the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867269/replace-only-text-inside-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xzc6m6ju/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try if this works

```
$('#country').clone().children().remove().end().text();
$('#capital').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

`.clone()` clones the selected element.

`.children()` selects the children from the cloned element

`.remove()` removes the previously selected children

`.end()` selects the selected element again

`.text()` gets the text from the element without children

Comment: This will return all the text content that are before and after the `span` element.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just edit the HTML ?

```
<div id="country">
    <span>B</span>
    <span class="text">Bangladesh</span>
</div>
<div id="capital">
    <span class="text">Dhaka</span>
    <span>D</span>
</div>
```

Then, using jQuery :

```
var one = $("#country>.text").text();
var two = $("#capital>.text").text();
```

Comment: Yo! Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Andy's answer, but this will remove all the elements so you do not have to do per child element removal, so no matter how many children or what structure is inside your div, it will always return the text

```
var clone = $('div#country').clone();
clone.find('*').remove();
console.log(clone.text());
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zghgm43/)

Comment: This is a nice upgrade to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the `contents` for text nodes (nodetype=3) and read the `textContent`:

```
var country = $('#country').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3
})[1].textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get that text by using `nextSibling` and `previousSibling`attribute.

**Example:**

```
$("#country").find("span")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
$("#capital").find("span")[0].previousSibling.nodeValue;
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/h0kboc36/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
answer = $('#capital').clone();
answer.children('span').remove();
alert(answer.text()); // alerts "text"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="country">
  <span>B</span>
  Bangladesh
</div>

<div id="capital">
  Dhaka
  <span>D</span>
</div>
```

Plenty of answers already.

You can use .clone() for that, like so:

```
answer = $('#capital').clone();
answer.children('span').remove();
alert(answer.text()); // alerts "text"
```

Using this format you can add other elements to your div and hopefully the code above is simple enough to be able to see how to remove them.

Original answer from : [get text in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706330/get-text-in-div)