# Selecting text inside div, why isn't .text working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Chrome's developer console. I'm trying to grab a piece of text from a website.

Example:

```
<div class="someClass">This is some text!</div>
```

I expected this to work, but it returns 'undefined'

```
$('.someClass')[0].text
```

Yet that does work when the text is inside a  tag with the same class. Is there something special occurring when the text is just inside a div? Thanks!

Comment: try `$('.someClass')[0].text()`

Comment: `$('.someClass').text()` or `$('.someClass').first().text()` or `$('.someClass:eq(0)').text()` (last two if you have more than one)

Comment: @miguelsolano wrong, that is an error.

Comment: because [0] returns the DOM node and DOM does not have text property.

Comment: Please run a search of the archives before asking a question. Look at question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299313/get-inner-text-from-div for an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This `$('.someClass')[0]` returns a DOM element and not a jQuery object.

So, what you could use instead is `$('.someClass')[0].textContent`

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks Ele!

Comment: @jesse_2567 you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Problem you have is you are using brackets to reference the first element. With jQuery, that [returns the DOM node](http://api.jquery.com/get/) and DOM does not have a text property.

You need to use .eq(0) to reference jQuery and it is a method so it would need parenthesis.

```js
console.log($('.someClass').eq(0).text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someClass">This is some text!</div>
```

Comment: This solves my problem, AND clears up my confusion between DOM nodes and Javascript objects. Thanks epascarello!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$('.someClass')
```

...returns a jQuery selection. You can get the text from that with:

```
$('.someClass').text()
```

However, if there is more than one `.someClass`, you'll get the text of all of those items. That may be why you have:

```
$('.someClass')[0]
```

...but that is no-longer a jQuery selection but is a DOM element which has neither a `.text()` method or a `.text` property. There is an `innerText` or `textContent` property, neither of which has wide browser support, so maybe you're best off doing:

```
$('.someClass').first().text()
```