# How to match children innerText with user input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="campaignTags">
    <div class="tags">Tag 1</div>
    <div class="tags">Tag 2</div>
    <div class="tags">Tag 3</div>
</div>
```

And I'm trying to match user input against the innerText of each children of `#campaignTags`

This is my latest attempt to match the nodes with user input jQuery code:

```
var value = "Tag 1";
$('#campaignTags').children().each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(value == $(this).context.innerText){
        return;
    }
```

The variable value is for demonstration purposes only.

A little bit more of context:

Each `div.tags` is added dynamically to `div#campaignTags` but I want to avoid duplicate values. In other words, if a user attempts to insert "Tag 1" once again, the function will exit.

Any help pointing to the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here's a fiddle that I just created:

http://jsfiddle.net/TBzKf/2/

**The lines related to this question are 153 - 155**

I tried all the solutions, but the tag is still inserted, I guess it is because the `return` statement is just returning the latest function and the wrapper function.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Why are you reinventing jQuery's `text()`

Comment: probably because I've been switching between symfony and javascript for the last 11 hours lol! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
var $taggedChild = $('#campaignTags').children().filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === value;
});
```

Here's a [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EYufr/), illustrating this approach in action:

---

But perhaps I'd use here an alternative approach, storing the tags within JS itself, and updating this hash when necessary. Something like this:

```
var $container = $('#campaignTags'),
    $template  = $('<div class="tags">'),
    tagsUsed   = {};
$.each($container.children(), function(_, el) {
    tagsUsed[el.innerText || el.textContent] = true;
});

$('#tag').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var tag = $.trim(this.value);
        if (! tagsUsed[tag]) {
            $template.clone().text(tag).appendTo($container);
            tagsUsed[tag] = true;
        }
    }
});
```

I used `$.trim` here for preprocessing the value, to prevent adding such tags as `'Tag 3 '`, `' Tag 3'` etc. With direct comparison ( `===` ) they would pass.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RTuBt/).

Comment: And then the check would be `if($taggedChild.length > 0){return;}` right?  Does filter still return an array of jQuery objects?  I'd expect it would.

Comment: It returns a jQuery object, right, so you should check its `length`.

Comment: I'd say this is the best answer.  Forgot about `filter` :)

Comment: This is a pretty good one unfortunately, when I used your snippet in the rest of my code it doesn't work, and I don't quite understand why. Would you mind checking the link that I posted just a few minutes ago?

Comment: Ignore the last comment, I didn't pay close attention to your demo! This worked like a charm!! thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#addTag').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var v = this.value,
            exists = $('#campaignTags').children().filter(function () {
                return $(this).text() === v;
            }).length;
        if (!exists) {
            $('<div />', {
                'class': 'tags',
                'text': v
            }).appendTo('#campaignTags');
        }
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2LTbS/).

This is based on a number of assumptions, obviously:

1. You want to add unique new tags,
2. You want the user to enter the new tag in an `input`, and add on pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "Tag 1";
$('#campaignTags').find('div.tags').each(function(){
   if(value == $(this).text()){
       alert('Please type something else');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user either **.innerHTML** or **.text()**

```
 if(value === this.innerHTML){ // Pure JS
       return;
  }
```

**OR**

```
if(value === $this.text()){   // jQuery
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it was a typo, but you were missing a close `}` and `)`.  Use the jquery `.text()` method instead of `innerText` perhaps?

```
var value = "Tag 1";
$('#campaignTags').find(".tags").each(function(){
  var content = $(this).text();
  if(value === content){
    return;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go try this: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3haLP/

Since most of the post above comes out with something here is another take on the solution `:)`

Also from my old answer: [jquery - get text for element without children text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

Hope it fits the need ':)' and add that justext function in your main customised Jquery lib

**Code**

```
 jQuery.fn.justtext = function () {

     return $(this).clone()
         .children()
         .remove()
         .end()
         .text();

 };

 $(document).ready(function () {
     var value = "Tag 1";
     $('#campaignTags').children().each(function () {
         var $this = $(this);
         if (value == $(this).justtext()) {
             alert('Yep yo, return');)
             return;
         }
     });

     //
 });
```