# How to get child element text using only javascript

Tags: javascript

I can get this done by using jquery but I need to get it done by using javascript. I am like a beginner in javascript. I need to get text node from div.

Div contains text node and then span and again text node in it. I can get text node inside div by using `firstChild` but how to get span text node.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
12345799
<span>my name </span>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
document.getElementById('test').firstChild.nodeValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('test').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].nodeValue
```

Comment: That's not what the question says, it says _how to get span text node_.

Comment: If you want to get the text of the parent without any of the children, see this question and the ones linked from it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text/11362182#11362182

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
var parent = document.getElementById('test');
string spanText = parent.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerText;
```

if `innerText` is not supported by your browser, you can also use

```
parent.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yb784/)