# javascript if div equals then

Tags: javascript, html

how do you make it in javascript on page load like, if div1 equals YES then div2 must display "You Said YES"

```
<div class="div1">YES</div> 
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Using `text()` function.

Comment: Attach event to body load and in that check the value of div1 then set the value of div2

Comment: with conditional statement, onload event and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695729/how-to-get-child-element-text-using-only-javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in plain javascript, you can use `body.onload` like this:-

HTML:-

```
  <body onLoad="onbodyload()">
   <div id="div1">YES</div> 
<div id="div2"></div>
  </body>
```

Javascript:-=

```
function onbodyload(){
        var d1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var d2 = document.getElementById('div2');
  if(d1.innerHTML==='YES'){
  d2.innerHTML='You Said Yes!';
  }
};
```

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qaFD1NQya3X4HSOk2hg8).

Answer (score 0):

Use onload event of body and do desired operation. Add id to the div for easy manipulation.

```js
document.body.onload=function(){
//first element with class div1
var div1=document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[0];
  if(div1.innerHTML=="YES"){
    //first element with class div2
    document.getElementsByClassName('div2')[0].innerHTML="You said Yes";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="div1" id="div1">YES</div> 
  <div class="div2" id="div2"></div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Not much effort in changing from id to class. But using id is much better than class.

Answer (score -2):

$('.div2').show().text("You said yes!");

```js
$(function() {
  if ($('.div1').text() == "YES") {
    $('.div2').text("You said yes!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">YES</div> 
<div class="div2"></div>
```