# jQuery selecting text from an element exclude child

Tags: jquery

```
var machine = $('h1').contents(':not(small, a)').text();
console.log(machine);

<h1>Title <small>subheading</small> <a href="#"></a></h1>
```

I am trying to get the text which is `Title` to display using the above jQuery but of course this console.logs a blank line. Basically excluding the `small` and `a` tags

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/5X8N8/)

Comment: you want to exclude small tag?

Comment: I removed the `.modal-left` in the fiddle and it works: [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/5X8N8/6/)

Comment: its working.....http://jsfiddle.net/5X8N8/13/

Comment: What you say about http://jsfiddle.net/5X8N8/10/

Comment: Check this  http://jsfiddle.net/5X8N8/18/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery - get text for element without children text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var machine = $("h1")
.clone()    //clone the element
.children() //select all the children
.remove()   //remove all the children
.end()  //again go back to selected element
.text();

alert(machine);
```