# Get HTML element text without children

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How would I receive only the direct text, not including children and children's text?

For example in this case I would like to receive "Lorem":

```html
<div>
  Lorem
  <div>
    Ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get a reference to the `div`, from your jQuery I'm assuming it has the class `title`

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0]; //get the reference to the parent div
var name = div.firstChild.nodeValue;

alert(name)
```

```html
<div class="title">
  hi
  <div>
    asd
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to complicate it

```js
var div = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0]; //get the reference to the parent div
var array = [].map.call(div.childNodes, function(child) {
  return child.nodeType == 3 && child.nodeValue.trim() ? child.nodeValue.trim() : undefined;
})
var name = array.join();

alert(name)
```

```html
<div class="title">
  hi
  <div>
    asd
  </div>
  this also
</div>
```

Comment: Arun, What does the [0] in the first line denote?

Comment: @MarsOne `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like `NodeList` so we need to access the first element from that using index

Comment: Of course this code only gets the first text node's text... Based on the jQuery version I suspect they may want all text (excluding all children), but the question is quite vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this way:

```
alert($(".title").clone().children().remove().end().text())
```

### Snippet:

```js
$(function(){
  alert($(".title").clone().children().remove().end().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">
  hi
  <div>
    asd
  </div>
</div>
```

or write your own function as shown [**in this SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text) in the jquery and can reuse it wherever needed.

```
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};

alert($('#mydiv').justtext());​
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works...

```
$('div').filter(function(){
    console.log( $.trim($(this).clone().context.firstChild.data) );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get hi only try this :

```
var element = $("div:first").text();
```

Comment: This will return hi asd.