# jquery selector - ignore child element

Tags: jquery

How do I select only the Text within the span but ignore the child span.

```
<span class="a">
   My Text for A
   <span class="b">*</span>
</span>
```

I would like to select only the text.  i.e. "My Text for A"...not  "My Text for A *" and if there are more than one it should return as an array like a normal selector.

```
$('.a').text();
```

Comment: See: [jquery - get text for element without children text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

Comment: This question should be closed and marked as duplicate.

Comment: @JusticeErolin - isn't it?

Comment: These don't return as an array though.

Comment: @KingKongFrog `and if there are more than one it should return as an array like a normal selector.` You want `.text()` to return a jQuery set???

Comment: And when I closed the question as a dupe, it didn't include the part about any arrays. You just added that.

Comment: yes, I left that part out on accident.

Comment: This is anyway already answered in dupe: `$('.a').contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    });`  This will returns a jq set. To get the text, call `.text()` on it