# Retrieve text from list tag but don't calculate the child tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to retrieve the calculation of the text within `<li>` but I don't need the child tag `<p>` to be considered in this calculation.
So when I add the following it will naturally calculate all the text within `<li>`.

```
$('ul li').text().length;
```

From HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Count me<p>Don't count me please.</p></li>
</ul>
```

What are the possible ways to achieve this so the child tags text is not calculated?

Comment: is it the child tag you dont want considering, or the contents of the child tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone the element, remove the children and then extract the text:

```
var li = $('ul li').clone();
li.children().remove();
console.log(li.text().length);
```

This will work regardless of the number or type of child elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract it?

```
var x = $('ul li').text().length;
var y = $('ul li p').text().length;
console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(x-y);
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual method of retrieving the text via selector will prove difficult because the `text()` method is greedy and will get all the text available to it, even if you exclude children via the selector.

If all you need is to retrieve the text which is directly within the `li` only you can get the `textNode` values from `contents()`:

```
var textNodes = $('ul li').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).get();
console.log(textNodes[0]); // = "Count me"
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kptqwxbb/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var len1 = $('ul li').text().length;
var len2 = $('ul li p').text().length;
console.log(len1+'=='+len2);

var liLength = parseInt(len1)-parseInt(len2);

console.log(liLength);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uzebasy7/)

Comment: No need for the parseInt

Answer (score 1):

possible duplicate of:
[jquery - get text for element without children text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

```
$('ul li').clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

Here an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zmy4mxc2/