# JavaScript/jQuery detect if div contains text excluding children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to verify if a DIV has some text or not inside of it BUT NOT inside its children, eg see this example

```
<div id='one'>
  <div id='two'>Abc</div>
</div>
<div id='three'>xyz
  <div id='four'></div>
</div>
```

If I hover/click element `one` I want to get `false` (no text), but if i hover element `three` I want to get `true`

i tried using

```
$('#one').text().trim().length > 0
```

but it seems to check also any children which is want I do not want to happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery - get text for element without children text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

Answer (score 4):

This is already answered here: [jquery - get text for element without children text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362085/jquery-get-text-for-element-without-children-text)

Also mentions using a plugin to accomplish getting only the text of the element and not child elements here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Comment: should have been closed as duplicate if you think it is answered already

Answer (score 0):

This meets your requirements

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var two = document.getElementById('two').textContent;
  console.log(two.trim()=='');
  var three = document.getElementById('three').textContent;
  console.log(three.trim()=='');
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>
    <div id='two'>Abc</div>
</div>
<div id='three'>
      <div id='four'></div>
</div>
```